# Select record with Highest value inside another select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need some assistance with a Select.

The following is an attempt to give you an example of the data.

> Number: 1 | Date: 2014-05-01 | ClientCode: 001 | Status: P | Sequence:
>   0 |
>
> Number: 1 | Date: 2014-05-01 | ClientCode: 001 | Status: X | Sequence:
>   1 |
>
> Number: 2 | Date: 2014-06-30 | ClientCode: 005 | Status: X | Sequence:
>   0 |
>
> Number: 2 | Date: 2014-06-30 | ClientCode: 005 | Status: Z | Sequence:
>   1 |
>
> Number: 2 | Date: 2014-06-30 | ClientCode: 005 | Status: A | Sequence:
>   2 |

I need a Select that give me all the records with the highest "Sequence" within the ones with the same "Number"

The desired output would return the lines with the Number 1/Sequence 1 and Number 2/Sequence 4

I managed to do this with the use a temp table but it is very slow.

Can you help me?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show us what you've done, the query with your temp table?

Comment: Hi All! 
Since i can not vote, I want to thank you all for your help. 
You solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this:

```
;WITH TestTable(Number, Date, ClientCode, Status, Sequence) AS(
    SELECT 1, '2014-05-01', '001', 'P', 0 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, '2014-05-01', '001', 'X', 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, '2014-06-30', '005', 'X', 0 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, '2014-06-30', '005', 'P', 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, '2014-06-30', '005', 'X', 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10, '2015-01-01', '555', 'P', 0 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 15, '2015-02-08', '666', 'P', 0 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 15, '2015-02-08', '666', 'C', 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 15, '2015-02-08', '666', 'T', 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 15, '2015-02-08', '666', 'X', 3 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 15, '2015-02-08', '666', 'X', 4
)
SELECT
    Number,
    Date,
    ClientCode,
    Status,
    Sequence
FROM(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY Sequence DESC)
    FROM TestTable
)t
WHERE RN = 1
```

**RESULT**

```
Number      Date       ClientCode Status Sequence
----------- ---------- ---------- ------ -----------
1           2014-05-01 001        X      1
2           2014-06-30 005        X      2
10          2015-01-01 555        P      0
15          2015-02-08 666        X      4
```

Comment: I've always used `ROW_NUMBER` for situations like this. However, this method can remove unexpected double records. In most situations you'd want to know if doubles occur. Now, I usually use `RANK` instead.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I think `ROW_NUMBER` is good enough for this since I'm assuming `Sequence` is unique. But yeah, `RANK` can be used to for this kind of problems.

Comment: Assumptions are dangerous :P

Comment: @HoneyBadger, yup. Danger is my last name. =)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 'a'
                    FROM table t2
                    WHERE t2.number = t.number
                    AND t2.sequence > t.sequence
                   )
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Number,
    Date,
    ClientCode,
    Status,
   Max( Sequence)
FROM
    TableName
Group by 
    ClientCode;
```

Just group by client code and use the max aggregate function on sequence to get the value associated with max sequence code.

Comment: Not working on most dbms products (nor in ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.

Comment: MySQL specific I believe. MySQL by default supports this "lazy group by" syntax  server settings can be altered such that this query type would be invalid. Don't use this syntax and be wary of the results from MySQL if using this syntax.

Comment: @Used_By_Already : i didnt knew that... Will try to avoide this kind of mysql syntax. .  thanks

Comment: Refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html note this sentence `The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. ` In short the abbreviated syntax produces "indeterminate" (unreliable) results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
With x as (select number, max(sequence)from yourfile group by number) 

select y.number,y.sequence,y.clientcode  
from x, yourfile y 
where x.number=y.number 
and y.sequence=x.sequence
```

Comment: Old style JOINS are not standard ANSI since 1992, please use `ON` keyword/style.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated sub-query to find each number's max sequence value:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName t1
where sequence = (select max(sequence) from tablename t2
                  where t1.number = t2.number)
```

Will return both rows if one number with two same max sequence rows.